# How to create box3 using Vector3 in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

There is a basic way to create box3 in three.js.
creating by min, max vector3.

I want to create a box3 composed of 8 vector3s.

I have tried '.setFromArray' method, but it was not effective for me.
(It only compares the minimum and maximum x, y, z and produces box3)

Do you have an idea to create a box3 composed of 8 vector3s?

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have an idea to create a box3 composed of 8 vector3s?

I suggest you use [Box3.setFromPoints()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3.setFromPoints). This will create an AABB enclosing all the 3D points in the given array.